# which power of the feature should i train with? regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I have a explanatory variable (x-axis) and a response variable (y-axis). I am trying to find which power of the feature i should train the dots with. You can ignore the colors for my question. [image: x=explanatory variable, y=response variable]

EDIT:
I used  `np.polyfit()` and `np.poly1d()` to see the order of the curved line, as it fits a bit to my data. the function is not injective for the case where my response variable is the y-axis, so i had to invert the plot:

[image: x=response variable, y=explanatory variable]

[image: polynomial orders]

Now i can choose which polynomial order to take, but this applies to the case where my response variable is the x-axis. I hope this explains my aim a bit.

Comment: So to get this right, you would like to model just the curved line? Or just the dots with the curved line? You're trying to determine whether to use x^2 and x^3?

Comment: @CameronChandler i would like to model the dots without the curved line. i would say yes to your second question, but does it have to be an integer?

Comment: Please expand on the number of training data, the aim of the regression, whether it has to be polynomial or could be a spline regression. Are you aware of the bias / variance dilemma? To small an order will lead to poor fit, to much to overfitting. Whether overfitting is a problem depends on the goal of the regression, measures to overcome it depend on the sample size.

Comment: @Bernhard i have 500k datapoints. What do you exactly mean by the aim of the regression? There is no need to limit the solution with polynomial regression. The bigger problem here is that my function is non-injective. Choosing the right order for the second plot is not my aim.

Comment: Spline regression looks like the way to go.

Comment: @CameronChandler will that solve the problem that my case is non-injective? can you give me an approach where to start?

Comment: Please add new information in comments to the post as an edit. Not everybody reads comments!